# Is there a way to find out how many emoji slots left to use on a guild?

Tags: javascript, discord

Is there a way to find out how many emoji slots left to use on a guild?
Or just a total amount of emoji slots available for a certain guild

discord.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/PremiumTier

**Guild PremiumTier**

The premium tier (Boost level) of a guild:

```
NONE     - 100 total slots
TIER_1   - 200 total slots
TIER_2   - 350 total slots
TIER_3   - 500 total slots
```

Can be used to count how many slots are available for a guild

The slots between usual and animated emojis spread equally, you can calculate the amount of slots left for each type, like this

( tier level slots / 2 ) - the amount of emojis already uploaded of one of the types

```js
var totalEmojiSlots;

if(message.guild.premiumTier == 1){
  totalEmojiSlots = 200;
} else
if(message.guild.premiumTier == 2){
  totalEmojiSlots = 350;
} else
if(message.guild.premiumTier == 3){
  totalEmojiSlots = 500;
} else {
  totalEmojiSlots = 100;
}

// And each emoji type takes half of total emoji slots
```